# Why does G-d care about small minutiae?

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy, halacha-theory

As an Orthodox Jew, I recently decided to start learning Shulchan Aruch to become more careful about halacha and my person conduct.

However, I have found myself in an unexpected hashkafic crisis. The laws - especially those that I am unused to - seem so technical. Does G-d really care which hand we take care of our needs in the bathroom with, or which shoe is removed first? While I have no problem with hard-to-keep laws that are written in or straight derivates of the Torah, I have a hard time understanding laws when I don't understand how they are derived from Torah, and I find myself wondering how keeping these laws is serving G-d.

If this question is off-topic, I would greatly appreciate it if it could be reformulated to fit the guidelines.